# Wordpress Transient

Tags: wordpress, transient

I am trying to learn some new database techniques and at the moment, I have a opportunity to apply and try something new.

Wordpress coined some of it's values: "transient" and lock it on to a key value.

Example Value:

a:20:{i:-1273996637;i:1284;i:-1273997086;}

What I like to know is the concept on how these values are created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "Transient" in WordPress is cached, temporary data. The data has an expiry timestamp, so it will be automatically deleted after a specified interval.

> *a simple and standardized way of storing cached data in the database
>   temporarily by giving it a custom name
>   and a timeframe after which it will
>   expire and deleted.*

So to answer your question: Some plugin (or WP itself) stored this data for some purpose, but it will be automatically purged at some point.

You can read the full details here: [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)

Comment: Nice answer. I was a little unclear on this myself. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Le gasp. I must have the wrong concept in mind :( Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: Anraiki: What concept/info are you looking for? Maybe I can guide you.